# Should we adopt "close shot" as a verb in casual writing?

Tags: colloquialisms, verbing

This question inevitably invites the controversial subject of [verbification](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/verbification-of-a-noun), but I wish a finer discussion on its possible benefits and drawbacks. My limited vocabulary perhaps has not alerted me to a verb currently in use that could play a better role. If so, then, I will not press the question further. Otherwise, what are the advantages and disadvantages of employing "close shot" (or "closeshot") in casual writing?

Edit:
I should have provided the meaning. I meant something akin to a microscopic snapshot of an object (or subject). Using a gun analogy, it would be like a close-range shot. But it is closer to the analogy of photography.

Edit 2:
In response to a question from Mitch: 
In standard usage, [closeup](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/closeup) and [close shot](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/close-shot?s=t) are nouns and imply an intimate or detailed view. Similar nouns: [closeup shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-up), [tight shot](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/tight%20shot). Canepari uses some of these words as nouns in discussing translation and discourses. For example, [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=SoKTAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA216&dq=%22close%20shot%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxo7aBwsPYAhWGON8KHYzoBUM4KBDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=%22close%20shot%22&f=false), on a footnote in page 216.  I found myself wanting to express this idea, however, in verbal form. For example, "Your pic closeshots (into) the obscure parts." Or, "Your essay closeshots (into or on) the heart of the matter." Another way of expressing this last sentence using standard wording: "your [essay zeroed in on the](https://afterdeadline.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/01/25/too-many-whoms/) heart of the matter." In short, I wonder about making the noun "close shot" into a verb, taking a close shot of an image or an issue. Or, as I mentioned in the original query, I wonder if there is a better word or way to express the same idea. Thanks.

Comment: I've read your question twice but may have missed it: what are you trying to express with the term "close shot"? (Is this something to do with the term *closeup* from photography?)

Comment: In casual writing you can write "glistophabe" if you want.  But if you want to be understood, "close shot", as a verb, is meaningless to most people.

Comment: Regarding protocols in this forum: I find it unfair that others would quickly rate my question down just because it does not make sense to them at first try. This question does not results from haste, but after searching for alternatives. It should be obvious from the footnote.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence from the real world (with link)? I don't know what you mean by 'close shot'.

Comment: Again, I do not see the use of continue to downvote my question when It was answered and it came after reflecting on it and doing some research about it. It was an exploratory question, and I was not even proposing anything, just asking if there would be a better way (which was answered). I think this downvoting system is broken.

Comment: ELU stands for English Language and **Usage**. DIY candidate words have been stated to be off-topic here numerous times.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth You should read my question and clarifications more carefully before shooting your comments. This is a question of **usage** and not about DIY candidate. Using a noun as a verb.

Comment: I think the expression that you want is [*zoom in (on)*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/zoom-in-out). This shares the photographic connotations of a "close shot" as the way to take such a close-up photo or video is usually to 
use the camera's *zoom* (or to move the camera closer, which is sometimes, somewhat controversially, called ["zooming with your feet"](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/content/id-rather-zoom-my-feet-huh-even-possible)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a neologism to be adopted, there must be a language community, however small, that immediately understands the new word or usage and begins to use it themselves. Fans of the TV series Project Runway, for instance, all know what happens if a contestant is *auf'ed*: Heidi Klum informs the designer that he/she has been eliminated, does a couple of air kisses, and says, "Auf Wiedersehen!" This does not mean, however, that we can look forward to a government official getting auf'ed any time soon. The usage will remain restricted to the group in which the word emerged.

Your suggestion lacks even this specialized group to take your word and make it their own. Plus, it doesn't fill any linguistic gap that *to zero in* or *to close in on* doesn't already fill.

Comment: I take, then, that what you are saying is that "to zero in or to close in on" appears to suffice our linguistic needs. And I think it is a fair answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Given Lawrence's comment alone (which I agree with), the answer is already clear: no. The term is made up and not understood by readers.

Comment: Of course it is made up. That is what new usage (i.e., verbification) is all about. But I wondered if a phrase (or word) like this one could still be understood or if there is a better way to express its idea.

Comment: Please close-vote such inappropriate questions, rather than dignify them with an 'answer'.

Comment: @Dionisio: Verbification works, because the reader still understands the word. Verbification itself is an example - it uses the suffix "-ification" which can be translated as "the act of conversion". But understanding is critical to language.

Comment: @MSalters My original intent was to gauge how "understandable" the word/phrase was.  Obviously, it is not that much. In addition to what was suggested above ("to zero in or to close in on"), I have thought about other substitutes: zoom in, look in closer, etc. So, for the colloquial/informal usage, the question is settled. Could I venture to ask what would be the best way to convey the same idea in an academic context? Zero-in and its variations seem to me a bit too informal. What do you say?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think you are mistaking my question and rushing to judge with downvotes. Your coarse comments compound them.